# Typescript eslint Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, aws-cdk, cicd

I have a CDK application written in typescript. Locally when I run `npm run eslint` there are no errors.

But when the same thing is run in gitlab pipeline I get this error

```
  1:1  error  Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved
```

here is my package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "8.10.109",
    "@types/jest": "27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^10.17.27",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.6.2",
    "@types/prettier": "2.6.0",
    "@types/yamljs": "0.2.31",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.30.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.30.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
    "aws-cdk": "2.67.0",
    "esbuild": "^0.16.7",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "ts-jest": "27.1.4",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  },
```

npm script

```
 "eslint": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx .",
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    es2021: true,
    node: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  extends: ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended", "standard", "prettier"],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
  rules: {
    "no-new": "off",
    camelcase: "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      "warn",
      { argsIgnorePattern: "^_.*" },
    ],
    "no-eq-null": "error",
  },
};
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
eslint:
  stage: static-test
  image:
    name: public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:16-alpine
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run eslint
```

What should I do to fix the error because locally it works. Should I change the name to `.eslintrc` instead of `.eslintrc.js` as many of the other issues have this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To prevent this error from happening

```
1:1  error  Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved
```

Change the name from `.eslintrc.js` to `.eslintrc.cjs` to indicate that you’re using CommonJS

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it solved but `partially`. I have 2 questions why does aslant command worked in my local system but it is failing in gitlab pipeline. Second After introducing your suggested changes I am getting this error `Don't use `object` as a type. The `object` type is currently hard to use ([see this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732)).
Consider using `Record<string, unknown>` instead, as it allows you to more easily inspect and use the keys  @typescript-eslint/ban-types` which again I am not seeing in my local system.

Comment: Since you’re using the plugin `typescript-eslint` there’s a rule that is applying which considers the `object` type as unsafe. For the Gitlab pipeline I’m not really sure why that’s happening

Comment: You could overwrite the `typescript-eslint` rule too

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, this is solved in typescript version 4.9.0 but `@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree.` supports only `TYPESCRIPT VERSIONS: >=3.3.1 <4.5.0`. If I replace it with `Record<string, unknown>` error is gone.

Btw why does adding cjs as file extension worked in gitlab while  `.js` worked in my local system? 
Is there a way to tell eslint through `.eslintrc` file that I am using commonJS or vice versa what should be done to keep `js as file extension`

Comment: from the docs: use .eslintrc.cjs when running ESLint in JavaScript packages that specify "type":"module" in their package.json. So probably you have set `type: module` in your package.json file

Comment: Its mentioned in tsconfig.json which was generated by cdk